# Spring boot does not receive headers from react js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm implementing a ReactJs applications.  I am using axios to invoke server side services built using Spring Boot.  I need to send the header "Authorization: Bearer token-value".  This is the client side code:

```
var options = {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer token-value'}
};
axios.post('http://localhost:9090/services/list', null, options)
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

This is the Spring Boot controller:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";

    private static String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME);
        if (header == null || header.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        header = header.trim();
        if (!header.startsWith(BEARER)) {
            return null;
        }
        return header.substring(BEARER.length()).trim();
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping(value = "/services/list", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTargets(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String token = getToken(request);
        if (token == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        DTOObject obj = goForTheBusinessObject(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is the CORS configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

If I invoke the service using curl I got the expected response:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer token-value" http://localhost:9090/services/list
```

If I invoke the service using post man, again I got the right answer.

But when I executed the ReactJS application, the server never receive the "Authorization" header.

Somebody help me please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing CORS issues, Implement this class to resolve this-

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter  implements WebFilter  {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (exchange != null) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

        if (exchange.getRequest().getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return Mono.empty();
        } else {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

    } else {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
}
```

For more info on CORS visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

**Update:** For scanning the component you can do following-

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.pck", // cors filter package
    useDefaultFilters = false)
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.
        run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Deen.  I already implemented what you say.  Now my problem is that Spring Boot is not finding the class.   I wrote a debug message into the method `filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain)` and I have added the name of the new class package to the scanners: `@ComponentScan, @ServletComponentScan`and as parameter of the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`, but the CORS are not being loaded for Spring Boot.  Any suggestion?... Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried this, @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.pkg"})?

Comment: @RDV, I have updated the answer. Can you try out this and let me know if it's working?